# Non-translated single quote

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a strange problem: htmlspecialchars(with ENT_QUOTES) and mysql_real_escape_string functions aren't translating single quote in `i've`(and some others words), all others are translated, what is the reason of that result?

Comment: If that is the case, you might have hit a bug, which is very unlikely. Post some code.

Comment: Code of what? Using of htmlspecialchars?

Comment: what's the source of the data? sure it's not a ` instead of ' ?

Comment: You are observing that `htmlspecialchars` and `mysql_real_escape_string` do not correctly escape `'`. The simplest test would be `echo htmlentities("'", ENT_QUOTES),mysql_real_escape_string("'");` (for `mysql_real_escape_string`, a database connection is required)

Comment: Are you sure it's a regular single quote and not a fancy quote like those MS Word and OpenOffice use? (you know, opening single quote and closing single quote)

Comment: @Robik Can you post your results of these functions? Here is mine `php > echo mysql_real_escape_string("i've"); >i\'ve  
php > echo htmlspecialchars("i've", ENT_QUOTES); >i&#039;ve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want escaping use [htmlentities()](http://docs.php.net/htmlentities)

Answer (score 2):

It may be that what you think is a normal quote (', or HTML `&apos;`) is actually a curly apostrophe (’, or HTML `&rsquo;`). This will not be transformed by `htmlspecialchars` (nor `mysql_real_escape_string`, as it is not a valid quote for MySQL). `htmlentities` should escape this.

Comment: Note that `&apos;` is unknown in HTML 4 and prior (see [character entity references in HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). It was [added in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-predefined-ent) (thus also known in *real* XHTML) and [in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/named-character-references.html#named-character-references).

Comment: @Gumbo Whoa, interesting! I wasn't aware of that.